# Get Folder count inside a directory in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the number of folders (sub folders) inside a parent folder in asp.net.

I tried `int directoryCount = Server.MapPath("~/folder1/folder2/").Length;`

But not getting correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) method to get the directories and count them like:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/folder1/folder2/"));
DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

int count = dirArr.Length; //Total directories under the folder
```

The above will return the sub directories under your path, it is not recursive, if you want to recursively find all the directories then use the overload [`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories Method (String, SearchOption)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325.aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/folder1/folder2/"),
                                          SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Yep, It works. Thanks. and one thing pls. How to get sub folder names to a text box from "DirectoryInfo" array?

Comment: @IsuruSenanayake, `diArr.First().Name` will give you the name and that you can assign to the textbox, but this will be `Name` of the first instance, you may want to use a grid/listbox to display all the names from the array